# selenium python TimeOutException during automation scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

is TimeOutException avoidable or is there any some way to fix this error?
the problem is, its randomly occur in any lines, so i cant specific which lines got TimeOutException
as for the code below, it appears on `detail_topic`. the error frequently happend when using actions such as click

```
#loop how many pages
for i in range(0, 10):
    #loop how many topic
    total = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="topic-list"]/card-topic')))
    #loop every topic
    for i in range(1, len(total)):
        
        time.sleep(0.5)
        topic = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="topic-list"]/card-topic[{}]'.format(i))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        shadow1 = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", topic)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        shadow1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a').send_keys(u'\ue007')
    
        detail_topic = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'detail-topic')))
        shadow2 = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", detail_topic)
        title = shadow2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.h2').text
        title_data3ab.append(title)

        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.back()
    
    pagination = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//paginate-button')))
    shadow_pagination = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", pagination)
    next_button = shadow_pagination.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.page-next')
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    actions.move_to_element(next_button)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    actions.click(next_button).perform()
```

i havent try&except since the error occur in random lines, so i need to figure out which one is the main issue, any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyway somehow i fix the issue by adding adblock on my webdriver
`chrome_options.add_extension('yourextensionchoice.crx') #had to be in the same path`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).